Не скачать Vpn Proton
коллеги. В консоли Linux Mint при попытке скачать VPN получил следующее:
$ wget https://repo2.protonvpn.com/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-all/protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.3-3_all.deb
--2024-04-05 14:28:10--  https://repo2.protonvpn.com/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-all/protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.3-3_all.deb
Распознаётся repo2.protonvpn.com (repo2.protonvpn.com)… 212.102.35.237
Подключение к repo2.protonvpn.com (repo2.protonvpn.com)|212.102.35.237|:443... соединение установлено.
Не удаётся установить SSL-соединение.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. Может блокировка ресурса Роскомнадзором?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Используйте какой-нибудь VPN, с VPN успешно скачивается) В данном случае возможно и роскомнадзор. Если бы сайт какую-нибудь 400 ошибку кидал (например), это бы могло означать что сам сайт блокирует.

Роскомнадзор заблокировал вам доступ, попробуйте другой впн чтобы скачать этот как вам посоветовали выше, либо арендуйте копеечный сервер и разверните OpenVPN и пользуйтесь собственным дешевым решением

Спасибо всем за помощь. Поработаю в предложенных направлениях
